# How to avoid being encircled by a body triangle?

Tags: brazilian-jiu-jitsu, mixed-martial-arts, forms, grappling, escapes

The following sequence shows a fighter crossing his legs around the waist of his opponent.

What could be some possible ways to avoid this situation?

Once caught in it, how does one get out?

To make the question objective and non-opinion-based, are there any examples somewhere of someone reverting successfully from this situation ?

[image: Overhead python] [image: Python rolled over to supine]

[image: To side] [image: Forcing submission]

Comment: This position is called back control or rear control in BJJ. (The first image is a specific version called "back mount" or "rear mount" because he is on top as well as being behind his opponent.) The crossed-legs position in the last image is called the "body triangle", so you're looking for escapes from the body triangle from the back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Against the back control body triangle, BJJ instructors generally recommend you

1. be good at grappling in general so you have the knowledge and body skill to understand and survive the position in the first place
2. consider counter-attacking the triangled foot with an [ankle lock](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HUnYDMXcsKo)
3. escape the position by [methodically unwrapping the legs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1jD039fPDyM)

Answer (score 5):

**Step one** of defending the body triangle is rolling to the side so that your opponent's feet are on the ground, rather than their knee.

**Step two** is turning into the body triangle. You need to turn belly up. Resist the urge to push on the body triangle, as you can get your arm trapped, and get rear naked choked easier. If you want to, grab hold of your opponent's non choking arm. It takes away the possibility of a rear naked choke.

**Step three** now that you've turned a complete 180 degrees, you're on top, and in full guard. Worst case is they out scramble you and take mount, which is better than getting your back taken and choked.

Answer (score 2):

I have been training in BJJ for more than two years, and I can tell you that body triangles should be the least of your worries. If you want to prevent one you can turn onto your side and trap your opponent's leg to prevent a body triangle. There is no submission directly from body triangle, so it's not much of a problem. To escape, follow these steps, QUICKLY:

1: If the triangle is not facing up (because most people in back control fall to one side), use your leg as a pendulum and swing so that the triangle is on the top side and your body weight is on the bottom leg.

2: Shuffle your legs so that they are directly under the figure-4.

3: Wrap your outside leg around the leg that isn't wrapped around your body so that their calf lies in the crook of your knee.

4: Position your body so that their leg is parallel with your center line. This is important.

5: Lay the foot of your unused leg on top of the other foot to form a sturdy post.

6: This is where it gets painful for your opponent. Drive your hips straight up towards the sky, while at the same time driving your feet into the ground. This should get your opponent to tap out very quickly.